# How to get a unicode fonts work in Ipad?

Tags: ipad, unicode, uifont

I want to do an application using (Indian language )Malayalam Unicode font.I have applied lots of Malayalam Unicode fonts like (RachanaMac.ttf and others) but the its not supporting all the characters even after using the custom font. I have done application using malayalam asciicode fonts ,its works perfectly when i use the respective custom font.

Can anyone help me to find a solution? Or is any method to convert unicode fonts to ascii encoded fonts?

Answer (score 0):

I there is already a font with iOS any way

You can try with AnjaliOldLipi font.

Here is the link to [download](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/varamozhi/1%20AnjaliOldLipi/0.730.01/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf)

or you can follow this way [Malayalam on mac](https://sites.google.com/site/macmalayalam/)